# Groups of order 1814400

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to know whether there exists a group with the following structure:

$G$ is a non-split extension of a cyclic group of order 3 ($C_3$) by the Janko group $J_2$ such that $G/C_G(C_3)$ has order $2$ . ($C_3$ is normal in $G$)

Moreover, if such a group exists how I can  introduce it to GAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$J_2$ is a simple group, so $G/C_G(C_3)$ could not possibly have order $2$. In fact the Schur Multiplier of $J_2$ has order $2$, so there can be no non-split extension $G$ with normal $C_3$ and $G/C_3 \cong J_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I thought if we have a central extension which is non-split we can  conclude this fact!    And since this extension is not central I got confused.

Comment: Any extension of a cyclic group by a nonabelian simple group (or, more generally, by a perfect group) is central.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks a million.